# Decoding binary to pdf

Tags: python, base64

I'm using a platform that, when you upload pdf's to it, converts the pdf with the base64 encode in Python. Then it stores the binary string in the database.

Now I want to decode the strings and write them to a local folder, so I thought to use the 'with open' structure and pass it the b parameter for binary and then it should create test.pdf based of my decoded string and write it to my desktop?
Yet this yields no results, what am I doing wrong here?

```
code = "My binary string"

with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as fout:
     fout.write(base64.decode(code, '~/Desktop'))
```

EDIT:

```
code = "My binary string"

with open('~/Desktop/test.pdf', 'wb') as fout:
     fout.write(base64.decodestring(code))
```

Example binary string in database: "65/658e9014babd33786821f3130c5f3a1cc1322ddf"
So I'm assuming it starts after the '/' mark?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`base64.decode(,)` takes files as args. you want to try

```
fout.write(base64.decodestring(code))
```

though your code example is not encoded. 
Here's a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import base64, os
code = 'TXkgYmluYXJ5IHN0cmluZw==\n'
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/test.pdf'), 'wb') as fout:
     fout.write(base64.decodestring(code))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to create test.pdf with this method?

Comment: @RandomPerson If you are really using `~` in your filename you will need to call `os.path.expanduser()` to have it converted into a real path. I've edited my answer with a working example.

Comment: Thanks! If I do so I get an unrecognizable pdf file. I've added an example of the string that is being saved in the database

Comment: Perhaps the dbase format needs some further unpacking before being decoded?  All pdf's start with the string `%PDF`. If you encode that it gives `JVBER...` which is nothing like what you have.

Comment: it appears decodestring() no longer works if you are using python 3.9. Instead you can use code.encode() then use decodebytes(). Works like a charm.