# create pdf file from Bindata with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pdf, binary

I have a collection in MongoDB stores users' resumes, and they are stored as:

[image]

I've tried use python to convert it with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428368/decoding-binary-to-pdf), but the generated file cannot be viewed as pdf file.

The python code has:

```
import base64, os
from pymongo import *

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client.local
collection = db.users


ppl = collection.find({
    "_id": "38M8GoJS57Tp9MsGM"
})[0]

bindata = ppl["profile"]["resume"]

with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/test.pdf'), 'wb') as fout:
     fout.write(base64.decodestring(bindata))
```

I wonder what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by directly changing

```
fout.write(base64.decodestring(bindata))
```

to

```
 fout.write(bindata)
```

Because binary data can get wrote in directly